# vector's size in C++

Tags: c++, linux, vector, size

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "mixmax.h"//<-here, there is random number generator called  mixmax
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
const unsigned long long int n=10000000;
vector < float > f(n);
vector < float > distance_1(n);
vector < float > distance_2(n);
rng_state_t s;
rng_state_t *x=&s;
seed_spbox(x,12345);//<-here we just devlare our random number generator
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
f[i]=int(n*get_next_float(x));//,<-here we just get random numbers,like    rand()
sort(f.begin(),f.end());
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   distance_1[i]=f[i]-i;
   distance_2[i]=(i+1)-f[i];
}
float        discrep=max(*max_element(distance_1.begin(),distance_1.end()),*max_element(dis    tance_2.begin(),distance_2.end()));
cout<<"discrep= "<<discrep<<endl;
cout<<"sqrt(n)*discrep= "<<discrep/sqrt(n)<<endl;
}
```

When I print `f.max_size()` (the vector declined above in code) gives me this huge number 4611686018427387903, but when I take n=10000000000, it does not work, it gives this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped).
```

(I tried it in Visual Studio under windows.)

What's the problem ??? If vectors do not work for big sizes, can anyone tell me how can I use vectors or arrays with very big sizes ???

Comment: Well 10 GB * `sizeof(float)` * 3 is a ton of memory to allocate. I'm going to guess your OS isn't letting you allocate it all for a good reason. Don't forget you're asking for contiguous blocks, too.

Comment: max_size is the maximum potential elements it can hold based on implementation limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/max_size/),

> ## std::vector::max_size
>
> Returns the maximum number of elements that the
>   vector can hold.
>
> This is the maximum potential size the container can reach due to
>   known system or library implementation limitations, **but the container
>   is by no means guaranteed to be able to reach that size: it can still
>   fail to allocate storage at any point before that size is reached.**

Hence, `vector` doesn't guarantee that it can hold `max_size` elements, it just an implementation limitation.

Also, [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) mentioned:

> Well 10 GB * `sizeof(float)` * 3 is a ton of memory to allocate. I'm
>   going to guess your OS isn't letting you allocate it all for a good
>   reason.

The OP asks,

> If vectors do not work for big sizes, can anyone tell me how can I use
>   vectors or arrays with very big sizes ???

Yes you can. Try [Roomy](http://roomy.sourceforge.net/) or [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

`max_size()` is different of `size()` and is different of `capacity()`

Current capacity is `n=10000000` so the last element is `distance_1[9999999]`

Comment: What does this have to do with the error OP is getting (`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'`)?

Comment: Hum, you're right. Maybe should I comment instead of answering ? Sorry I'm new and some rules are not obvious...

Answer (score 0):

> What's the problem ???

Presumably, the allocation fails because your computer doesn't have 120GB of memory available. `max_size` tells you how many elements the implementation of `vector` can theoretically manage, given enough memory; it doesn't know how much memory will actually be available when you run the program.

> If this vectors do not work for big sizes Can anyone tell me how can I use vectors or arrays with big, very big size ???

Increase the amount of RAM or swap space on your computer (and make sure the OS is 64-bit, though from the value of `max_size()` I guess it is). Or use something like [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) to use files to back up huge data structures.

Comment: I'm writing my code in linux, whatever it does not work in Visula Studio 2013 too , what memory do you mean about, when you say 120GB memory????

Comment: @Narek: 3 vectors, each with 10000000000 floats, each of which is (presumably) 4 bytes. That's 120GB.

Comment: Thank you very much for useful reply, and one more question, this 120GB memory I need for RAM ?  When program is running , it takes a memory from RAM ? Thank you again very much

Comment: @Narek: Yes, RAM (Random Access Memory) is the memory used by running programs. You don't want to get 120GB of that - that's much more than most computers have, and would cost a fortune (if your computer can even support that much). If you really need to deal with that much data, you'll need to either configure your OS to use more disk space for swapping, or use file-based storage, perhaps using a library like the one I suggested in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much , now I understand things much more